# Image units break up

Tags: css

I have single image where all mine site logos/images are clubbed,so how i can fetch required image from main image like logos,arrows etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're referring to a sprite sheet. Take a look at [this link](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/). It helped me out a lot. If you need any help with it after that let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Sound's like your using sprites. There's numerous articles out there dealing with this technique:

http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites
http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=447210

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
#logo { 
  background: url(main_image.png);
  background-position: 50px -100px;
  }
```

The `background-position` property is the most important part. You'll want to find the exact pixel locations of each image (any image editor) before you start adding it to your CSS.